# Groovy: How to add a list as key and another list as values to a Map

Tags: list, groovy, maps

How can I add `mylist` as `keys` and `myanotherlist` as `values` to `myMap`

```
def mylist = [ John, Paul, Emily ]
def myanotherlist = [ 23, 45, 56 ]

def myMap = [:]
//
  println "myMap: ${myMap}"
  println "Age of Paul is: ${myMap['Paul']}"
```

Desired output:

```
  myMap: [
    John : 23 
    Paul : 45
    Emily : 56
   ]

 Age of Paul is: 45
```

Comment: You aren't asking for a list *as* a key; you want to get your keys *from* a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collectEntries` on a list of indices (`0` to `mylist.size()`):

```
def myMap = (0..<mylist.size()).collectEntries{[(mylist[it]) : myanotherlist[it]]}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can transpose the lists together (zip in other languages), then collect the entries

```
[mylist, myanotherlist].transpose().collectEntries()
```